# AWS - Link IP to domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a wordpress EC2 instance, but every time I restart the IP gets changed so I have to develop site on a new IP which is very inefficient.

My questions are:

1. Is there IP or something which is fixed so that I don't have to develop wordpress website in different IP every time. Since I am researching here free option is preferred?
2. Let's say once my website is complete, how can I point this IP to my domain?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html -> you can use an elastic IP address and then reference that IP in your DNS. Costing for elastic IPs: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Elastic_IP_Addresses - in summary, in certain conditions an elastic IP is free.

Or you could put your EC2 behind a loadbalancer and then reference the load balancers DNS name (ie cname your web address to the load balancers DNS address). You probably want to use the Application Load Balancer. https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/ - this is not free but does present certain advantages over directly referencing the public IP in DNS.